# Backbone.js: The "Backbone.Collection" class supporting objects of different types, and how the class works

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

From reading a textbook called "Developing Backbone.js Applications" by Addy Osmani and trying out a practical example on it, I can see that all elements of the Backbone.Collection class can have elements of different types. A class extending Backbone.Collection can also hold different types of elements, like all elements don't have to be consistent.

Let me show you the code I'm using for my example:

```
var ToDosCollection = new Backbone.Collection();

ToDosCollection.add([
    { title: 'go to Jamaica.', completed: false },
    { task: "aldvjalkdgj", level: 3, timeDue: "6:00 PM Today" }
]);

console.log('Collection size: ' + ToDosCollection.length);
ToDosCollection.reset([
    { slogan: "Curse you, Sephiroth.", population: 5500,},
    { project: "Final Fantasy X" },
    { amount: 500 }
]);

// Above logs 'Collection reset.'
console.log('Collection size: ' + ToDosCollection.length);
alert(JSON.stringify(ToDosCollection.get(0)));

var GitHubRepository = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
        nameOfRepository : "",
        owner : "",
        members : [],
        dateCreated : "",
        commits: 0,
        additions: 0,
        deletions: 0,
    },

    initialize : function(){
        this.on("change", function() {
        console.log("CHANGE DETECTED");
    });

    this.on("change:nameOfRepository", function(){
        console.log("The name of the repository has been changed.");
    });

    this.on("change:owner", function(){
        console.log("The owner of the repository has been changed.");
    });

    this.on("change:members", function(){
        console.log("The members this repository belongs to have been changed.");
    });

    this.on("change:dateCreated", function(){
        console.log("The date this repository was created has been changed.");
    });

    this.on("change:commits", function(){
        console.log("The # of commits this repository has have been changed.");
    });

    this.on("change:additions", function(){
        console.log("The # of additions this repository has have been changed.");
    });

    this.on("change:deletions", function(){
        console.log("The # of deletions this repository has have been changed.");
        });
    }
});

var GitHubRepositoryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: GitHubRepository
});

var newCollection = new GitHubRepositoryCollection();

newCollection.add(
    {newObject: new GitHubRepository()},
    {title: "Rabbits"},
    {elementNumber: 5}
);
```

Am I understanding this correctly? Or, for some insight, how does this actually work? To me, I feel like I am making this analogous to an instance of the ArrayList in Java that supports Object objects.

EDIT: Considering that I have gotten at least one negative vote on this question, I would like to ask, "How does ItemView in Backbone.js work?"

Comment: As far as I understood it, a specific collection can contain only an array of specific models (like your `GitHubRepositoryCollection`) and an unspecific Collection can contain anything. See this, from the backbone documentation: "collection.model: 
Override this property to specify the model class that the collection contains. If defined, you can pass raw attributes objects (and arrays) to add, create, and reset, and the attributes will be converted into a model of the proper type."

Answer (score 0):

In order to render itemview for each model in the collection i guess it is better to keep each model analogous.Otherwise you will have to build itemview for each model differently which will increase you overheads to write code which is not good because we are supposed to use backbone in order to render the views which are to be rendered for same data in same way.if you want to render different itemview it is always better to have different composite or collection views which will automate your task of rendering the itemview which eventually will reduce your overheads.

Comment: @GregPDesJav Itemview is the view which backbone renders by itself for each model in collection, provided you have given itemview and itemviewcontainer in the collection or compositeview

Comment: @nikhilmehta your are mixing up marionette and backbone. Marionette is view and architechture extension for backbone. Backbone itself does not support itemviews